# Scala strange behavior "value x is not a member of"

Tags: scala

I came upon a strange bug today :

```
class Klazz[A](a: A) {
  def func[B](f: A => Klazz[B]): B = f(a).a
}
```

The code seems ok, but the compiler rejects it :

```
Error:(77, 8) value a not a member of com.sandbox.Klazz[B]
def func[B](f: A => Klazz[B]): B = f(a).a
```

When I however put this in a case class, there is no problem :

```
case class Klazz[A](a: A) {
  def a[B](f: A => Klazz[B]): B = f(a).a
}
```

Any idea why is this happening ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

case classes automatically set any value in the primary constructor as an immutable field in the class.

With a regular class you need to add the `val` keyword to the value declaration:

```
class Klazz[A](val a: A)
```

Comment: I will accept your answer, but any idea about we could make this using a call-by-name value ?

Comment: Not the first time you beat me to it, Yuval!

Comment: Actually, I've just figured out by myself by looking at how Try is implemented and by using a lazy in front of the value. This looks weird but works, thank you :)

Comment: This is still weird when you think about it, why doesn't the compiler blocks on the missing val keyword ? The error seems misleading.

Comment: Francis, because not having a val there is perfectly ok, it just means that the value is just available during object construction, the 'val' is optional and makes it also a member of the object.

Comment: Generally, a ctor param without any `val` or `var` is taken as if it were `private[this] val`. If it is never used in a `def` or `lazy val` within the class, no field is generated (I think if it's used in a `var/val` it just uses the ctor param in the ctor itself). Because it is `private[this]`, such a field can only be accessed by the current object; not even two objects of the same class will see the other's.